# squid proxy - add ip addresses

Tags: windows-server-2003, squid

I have installed squid proxy on my Windows Server 2003, it is working with 127.0.0.1. Please guide me how to:

1) I have assigned ip addresses, how can I add those ip addresses with squid?
2) How can I authenticate by ip address so only few specific ip address can use squid?

Thanks

Comment: I have managed it to work. But, it is picking all of assigned IP addresses, please let me know if there is any way to exclude any ip from squid proxy?

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed everything and it worked.